# Can I access android's "/system","/data",and "/mnt" with FileProvider ? If so,how?

Tags: android, android-fileprovider

I am trying to create an app that saves the installed apks on user storage(normal internal phone memory that we can use to store our own files).I did it very well with normal "Uri.fromFile()". But when i used "FileProvider.getUriFromFile()",it is showing the following error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.ragib.apkbackup, PID: 13200
              java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /data/app/com.example.ragib.apkbackup-1/base.apk
                  at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider$SimplePathStrategy.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:738)
                  at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:417)
                  at com.example.ragib.apkbackup.MainActivity$7$2.onMenuItemClick(MainActivity.java:502).........................[and many more]
```

and my manifest file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="@string/authority"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true"
        android:exported="false">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/shareable_paths" />
    </provider>

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
 android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden|screenLayout">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

and the meta-data resource is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
<external-path name="device_app_path" path="system/"/>
<external-path name="sd_card_app_path" path="data/"/>
<external-path name="system_app_path" path="mnt/asec/"/>
</paths>
```

I know that the error is occuring because 'external-path' is same as Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() and it doesn't contain the /system...

My question is,is there any way to gain access to those folder?
I am just a beginner. Sorry if the question is stupid :(

Answer (score 0):

> is there any way to gain access to those folder?

Not with `FileProvider`. You would need to write your own `ContentProvider`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like this?

```
<root-path
    name="mount"
    path="/mnt/" />
```